# How to tell node my script is not a module

Tags: node.js, package.json

How can I tell node that my script is not a module?
Apparently if anything in node_modules is a module node will think my script is a module and fail with: `Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: Must use import to load ES Module:`

Comment: could you explain a bit more what you are trying to do? where is your script located? what do you have in package.json?

Comment: The package.json is for a react app, but I just want to run a simple node script from the same folder without having to delete node_modules every time.

Comment: which node version are you using, and what your script looks like?

Comment: @Cuong - v14.16.1 and it fails at `const fetch = require('node-fetch')`

Comment: Probable duplicates https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61670459/nodejs-must-use-import-to-load-es-module, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57169793/error-err-require-esm-how-to-use-es6-modules-in-node-12, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61905905/error-err-require-esm-must-use-import-to-load-es-module

Answer (score 1):

As you mentioned you are using `node-fetch`, and node v14.16.1. Inside `node-fetch` documentation

> node-fetch is an ESM-only module - you are not able to import it with require. We recommend you stay on v2 which is built with CommonJS unless you use ESM yourself. We will continue to publish critical bug fixes for it.

So you have 2 options here:

- Continue using `node-fetch` 3, and change to `import fetch from 'node-fetch';`. You may need to change your script to [.mjs](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v14.x/docs/api/packages.html#packages_determining_module_system).
- Downgrade to `node-fetch` 2 to be able to use `require`.

Comment: Hmm. I guess I won't be using node-fetch anymore.